# Cannot pass file matching pattern to pipeline template

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm developing a pipeline template for Azure DevOps.
I've passed a file matching pattern as a parameter to my template, but it doesn't work as I expected.

pipeline-template.yaml

```
parameters:
- name: projects
  type: string
  default: '**/*.csproj'
- name: buildConfiguration
  type: string
  default: 'Release'
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build dotnet code'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: ${{ parameters.projects }}
    arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
```

azure-pipeline.yaml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
- template: pipeline-template.yaml
  parameters:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
```

I got this build error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
    Full command line: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -consoleloggerparameters:Summary -property:Configuration=Release D:\a\1\s\src\My.FirstApp.Tests\My.FirstApp.Tests.csproj -dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.202.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.202.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" 
  Switches appended by response files:
Switch: CPU

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

This is very simple.  I don't know why it wouldn't work.
Please let me know what is wrong.

Here is what I tried already:

- Printed parameters in the template; the string '**/*.csproj' was printed.
- Changed the parameter type to object; it didn't change, and I got the same error.

**---( Added: May 23rd, 2022 )---------**

Before creating the template, I tried the pipeline below, and it worked.
I can't tell the difference between this and the original template.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
variables:
  - name: project
    value: '**/*.csproj'
  - name: buildConfiguration
    value: 'Release'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build dotnet code'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: $(project)
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: I just copy your pipeline to a solution I have with multiple dotnet csproj projects I have and it works without issues.

Comment: Could it be the pattern matches more than one project and that's causing the `MSB1008: Only one project can be specified` error?

Comment: @Bohemian
 Thank you for your comments. Yes, the projects matching the pattern are multiple. But when I wrote the same task in pipeline directly, and set the same pattern in projects element, that worked. What's different on this?

Comment: The projects parameter in DotNetCoreCLI@2 was defined as 'multiline', but I wonder the parameter type 'multiline' is not supported in template.
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/04db9836c5a94bee612b926208aa169a74e74821/Tasks/DotNetCoreCLIV2/task.json#L102

Comment: I have the same test results as Maytham Fahmi. I have two .csproj files, and I completely copied your code without making any changes, but my pipeline can run successfully.

Comment: I am terribly sorry. I mis-quoted the code. Actually I had a platform parameter in build arguments, but I trimmed it while I wrote this question. For the configuration parameter, I passed 'Any CPU', but it includes a whitespace, and the whitespace was bad. I finally fixed the parameter into "AnyCPU" (no whitespace), and then it worked as I expected.